# How to draw a circle that stays in the center of a leaflet.js map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How do I draw a circle that stays in the center of a leaflet.js map?
E.g. The circle has the radius of 1 km. I want the circle to be drawn and stay at the center of the image no matter how the user pans. If the user zooms, the circle should change the size accordingly.

I wonder if I have to do it outside of leaflet and create another canvas or is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen on the `move` event on the map.

```
var circle = L.circleMarker(mymap.getCenter(), {
  radius: 50,
  color: 'red',
  fillOpacity: 0.2,
}).addTo(mymap);


mymap.on('move',function(e){
  circle.setLatLng(mymap.getCenter());
  mymap._renderer._update();
});
```

Also you can add `scrollWheelZoom: 'center'` to zoom always by the circle.

```
L.map('mapid',{scrollWheelZoom: 'center'})
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/q2mdow5c/

Comment: Your circle is 50 pixels ... not 1 kilometer

Comment: Yes you are right, but has only said for example 1km. And on zoom level 8 1km is very small. If you want to have exact 1km use L.circle

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer from Falke Design is nice and very straight forward but it uses L.Map private methods (not documented).

A more generic solution would be to:

1. Create a div above the map to hold you circle. The position and the size of the div will be recalculated each time the map is zoomed (you need to use leaflet map functions for these calculations).
2. Mouse events caught by this div need to be dispatched to the map (they won't bubble as the center div is not a child of the map div)

Here is an example: https://yafred.github.io/leaflet-tests/20200412-draw-circle-in-the-middle-of-the-map/

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <style>
    #center {
        visibility: hidden;
        top: -215px; 
        left: 285px;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        opacity: 0.4;
        background-color: blue;
        z-index: 650;
        position: relative;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden">
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<div id="center"></div>
</div>
<p>Zoom in or out.</p>
<p>The circle is redrawn to have a 1km diameter.</p>
<div id="events">
</div>

<script>

    var map = L.map('map').setView([48.858475, 2.338285], 13);

    L.tileLayer('//a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="//www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
    L.control.scale().addTo(map);

    // Map event handlers
    function zoomEnd(e) {
        var widthMeters = map.distance(map.getBounds().getNorthWest(), map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
        var widthPixels = map.getSize().x;
        var heightPixels = map.getSize().y; 
        var radiusPixels = Math.round(1000 * widthPixels / widthMeters);

        // change style
        document.getElementById('center').style.height = 2*radiusPixels + 'px';
        document.getElementById('center').style.width = 2*radiusPixels + 'px';
        document.getElementById('center').style.left = (Math.round(widthPixels/2) - radiusPixels) + 'px';
        document.getElementById('center').style.top = '-' + (Math.round(heightPixels/2) + radiusPixels) + 'px';
        document.getElementById('center').style.visibility = "visible";

        // log
        document.getElementById('events').innerHTML += 'zoom ' + map.getZoom() + '<br/>'; 
        document.getElementById('events').innerHTML += 'width in meters ' + Math.round(widthMeters) + '<br/>'; 
        document.getElementById('events').innerHTML += 'width in pixels ' + widthPixels + '<br/>'; 
        document.getElementById('events').innerHTML += 'radiusPixels ' + radiusPixels + '<br/>'; 
        document.getElementById('events').innerHTML += 'top ' + (0 - Math.round(heightPixels/2) + radiusPixels) + '<br/>'; 
    }
    function zoomStart(e) {
        document.getElementById('events').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('center').style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    }

    map.on('zoomstart', zoomStart);
    map.on('zoomend', zoomEnd);

    centerEventDispatcher = function(e) {
        new_e = new e.constructor(e.type, e);
        document.getElementById("map").dispatchEvent(new_e);
    }
    document.getElementById("center").addEventListener("mousedown", centerEventDispatcher);
    document.getElementById("center").addEventListener("mouseup", centerEventDispatcher);
    document.getElementById("center").addEventListener("mousemove", centerEventDispatcher);

    // initial circle
    zoomEnd();
</script>


    <!-- analytics -->
    <script>
if(window.location.hostname != "localhost") {
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-21317761-7', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

YaFred's approach is good but it's much simpler to pass mouse events through the circle to the map by using the newish `pointer-events: none;` css property on the circle.

So basically:

- draw your map
- add a circle-shaped div below it, using css something like...

```
    .radius-circle {
        border-radius: 50%;
        opacity: 0.4;
        background-color: blue;
        z-index: 650;
        position: relative;
        height: 160px;
        width: 158px;
        left: 220px;
        top: -280px;
        pointer-events: none;    
    }
```

Note negative top margin to pull it up over the map, and pointer-events setting to make mouse events pass through.

That's basically all you need to do.